# animated_text_kit: package in flutter. Do anybody work with this popular package? How several text's animation can be synchronized?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, text, package

```
ColorizeAnimatedTextKit(repeatForever: true, text: [tariff.name], textStyle: MyTextStyles.headline3, 
                    colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow, Colors.red,], textAlign: TextAlign.start,
```

i need to synchronize these texts animation. Do anybody know without modifying package?
[image]

Comment: Do you try this "animated_text_kit" ?  Use this package and try to set timer

Comment: Yes in the title i write that. yes i set Duration for pause parameter.

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: No, need to modify with animation controller